# Why are these two datetimes not equal?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, dst

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

chi = ZoneInfo("America/Chicago")
nyc = ZoneInfo("America/New_York")
dt1 = datetime(2024, 3, 10, 3, 30, tzinfo=chi)
dt2 = datetime(2024, 3, 10, 2, 30, tzinfo=chi)
print(dt1 == dt1.astimezone(nyc))
print(dt2 == dt2.astimezone(nyc))
```

Actual result:

```
True
False
```

Expected result:

```
True
True
```

Why is `False` returned in one of those cases? In both cases it's comparing the same datetime, only adjusted to a different zone.

The same thing also happens in the fold:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

chi = ZoneInfo("America/Chicago")
nyc = ZoneInfo("America/New_York")
dt1 = datetime(2024, 11, 3, 2, 30, tzinfo=chi)
dt2 = datetime(2024, 11, 3, 1, 30, tzinfo=chi)
print(dt1 == dt1.astimezone(nyc))
print(dt2 == dt2.astimezone(nyc))
```

Comment: There is no such time as 2:30am on March 10 in Chicago.  It's the changeover from standard time to daylight time.  I don't know what Python returns.

Comment: It works for `2021`. But the unix time of `dt1` and `dt2` are not equal for neither year.

Comment: @MSH DST started on March 14th in 2021.  It started on March 10 in 2024 and 02:30 doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Python's datetime by design allows to create non-existing datetime, like 2:30 am on Mar 10 2024 [Chicago time](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/usa/chicago) in your example. That's the root of the evil here. You cannot do a correct conversion to another tz without (silently) shifting to a valid datetime (3:30 am in this case). This shift is what's causing the comparison to be False in the second case. To illustrate, you can do a conversion roundtrip:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

chi = ZoneInfo("America/Chicago")
nyc = ZoneInfo("America/New_York")

dt1 = datetime(2024, 3, 10, 3, 30, tzinfo=chi)
dt2 = datetime(2024, 3, 10, 2, 30, tzinfo=chi) # non-existent !

print(dt1 == dt2) # False

print(dt1.astimezone(nyc)) # 2024-03-10 04:30:00-04:00
print(dt2.astimezone(nyc)) # also 2024-03-10 04:30:00-04:00 !

print(dt1.astimezone(nyc).astimezone(chi)) # 2024-03-10 03:30:00-05:00
print(dt2.astimezone(nyc).astimezone(chi)) # also 2024-03-10 03:30:00-05:00 !
```

`dt2` converted to NY time converted back to Chicago time comes back with different (now valid) fields - 2 am became 3 am. Those times are not equal and the comparison correctly returns False.

---

For completeness, here's what happens if you put this example on the other side of a DST transition, DST active to inactive:

```py
dt1 = datetime(2024, 11, 3, 1, 30, tzinfo=chi)  # ambiguous; exists twice (UTC-5 and UTC-6)
dt2 = datetime(2024, 11, 3, 2, 30, tzinfo=chi)

print(dt1, dt1.astimezone(nyc)) # 2024-11-03 01:30:00-05:00 2024-11-03 01:30:00-05:00
print(dt1.fold, dt1.astimezone(nyc).fold)  # 0, 1

print(dt1 == dt1.astimezone(nyc)) # False
print(dt2 == dt2.astimezone(nyc)) # True
```

You notice for `dt1`, both Chicago and NY have the same wall time and UTC offset - but those datetimes fall on different sides of the "DST fold" since the time zones are not the same. NY time is ahead of Chicago's, so it's already experiencing Winter time, while Chicago is still on the Summer side. Therefore, the datetimes are not identical and the comparison returns False.

Comment: This does not explain the issue - using `dt1 = datetime(2024, 11, 3, 2, 30, tzinfo=chi)` and `dt2 = datetime(2024, 11, 3, 1, 30, tzinfo=chi)` instead, both datetimes are existing, and they both correctly roundtrip.

Comment: @nosteponsnek both datetimes in your comment above exist, they round-trip correctly and if you call the comparison from your question, the result is as expected: True in both cases. Again, the unexpected result you got is caused by creating a non-existing datetime in a DST transition. Otherwise, everything is correct.

Comment: No it doesn't, it shows `True` `False` for this case.  See for example here https://trinket.io/python3/ed2bdff11d

Comment: @nosteponsnek sorry, I didn't notice you switched to Nov there, read it as 03-11 ;-) OK so this time you are landing on an ambiguous datetime, it can exist on both sides of the DST fold. I have updated the answer, hope that clarifies.

Comment: @nosteponsnek btw. the [DST tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info) has a nice illustration of the DST gaps ("spring forward") and folds ("fall backward")